# chrome not caching js & css but caches images

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, caching

Recently I started noticing my JS and CSS files are not getting cached in chrome and always reloaded from server.

But images and fonts are getting loaded from cache.

Below is the server response for javascript file. **Did something change in chrome behavior?** this is not happening in FF or IE!

Please help!

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "282766-1400285984000"
Date: Wed, 18 Nov 2015 18:27:05 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Last-Modified: Sat, 17 May 2014 00:19:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Answer (score 5):

On a mac using this version of chrome: Version 54.0.2840.87 (64-bit) I have found that javascript files are not cached if the site you are accessing is untrusted (ie: https to a site/localhost using a self signed certificate)

Comment: I've also seen this to be true.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your cache to maximum (even for javascript files):

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
```

- **365 days in seconds = 31,536,000 seconds**
- 1 month in seconds = 2,629,743 seconds
- 1 week in seconds = 604,800 seconds
- 1 day in seconds = 86,400 seconds

Chrome is working with resources another way, when you have opened developer tools. (Both can be changed in settings.)

Please share what server are you using to be able to help with specific configuration...